# Ruby - Return a particular value from hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm making a Ruby app that will allow someone to see the weather conditions in their area when they enter their zip code. Initially, it gives me this long hash (this is only a portion of it):

```
ekday_short"=>"Thu", "weekday"=>"Thursday", "ampm"=>"PM",  "tz_short"=>"EDT", "tz_long"=>"America/New_York"}, "period"=>1, "high"=>{"fah
renheit"=>"86", "celsius"=>"30"}, "low"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"70", "celsius"=>"21"}, "conditions"=>"Thunderstorm", "icon"=>"tstorms", "icon_
url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/tstorms.gif", "skyicon"=>"", "pop"=>80, "qpf_allday"=>{"in"=>0.39, "mm"=>10}, "qpf_day"=>{"in"=>0.3,
 "mm"=>8}, "qpf_night"=>{"in"=>0.08, "mm"=>2}, "snow_allday"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_night"=
>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "maxwind"=>{"mph"=>15, "kph"=>24, "dir"=>"ESE", "degrees"=>103}, "avewind"=>{"mph"=>10, "kph"=>16, "dir"=>"ESE
", "degrees"=>103}, "avehumidity"=>59, "maxhumidity"=>0, "minhumidity"=>0}, {"date"=>{"epoch"=>"1431126000", "pretty"=>"7:00 PM EDT on 
May 08, 2015", "day"=>8, "month"=>5, "year"=>2015, "yday"=>127, "hour"=>19, "min"=>"00", "sec"=>0, "isdst"=>"1", "monthname"=>"May", "m
onthname_short"=>"May", "weekday_short"=>"Fri", "weekday"=>"Friday", "ampm"=>"PM", "tz_short"=>"EDT", "tz_long"=>"America/New_York"}, "
period"=>2, "high"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"88", "celsius"=>"31"}, "low"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"72", "celsius"=>"22"}, "conditions"=>"Chance of a Thu
nderstorm", "icon"=>"chancetstorms", "icon_url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancetstorms.gif", "skyicon"=>"", "pop"=>60, "qpf_allday
"=>{"in"=>0.13, "mm"=>3}, "qpf_day"=>{"in"=>0.13, "mm"=>3}, "qpf_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "snow_allday"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "
snow_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "maxwind"=>{"mph"=>10, "kph"=>16, "dir"=>"SSW", "degrees"=>198
}, "avewind"=>{"mph"=>9, "kph"=>14, "dir"=>"SSW", "degrees"=>198}, "avehumidity"=>64, "maxhumidity"=>0, "minhumidity"=>0}, {"date"=>{"e
poch"=>"1431212400", "pretty"=>"7:00 PM EDT on May 09, 2015", "day"=>9, "month"=>5, "year"=>2015, "yday"=>128, "hour"=>19, "min"=>"00",
 "sec"=>0, "isdst"=>"1", "monthname"=>"May", "monthname_short"=>"May", "weekday_short"=>"Sat", "weekday"=>"Saturday", "ampm"=>"PM", "tz
_short"=>"EDT", "tz_long"=>"America/New_York"}, "period"=>3, "high"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"87", "celsius"=>"31"}, "low"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"74",
 "celsius"=>"23"}, "conditions"=>"Clear", "icon"=>"clear", "icon_url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif", "skyicon"=>"", "pop"=>2
0, "qpf_allday"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "qpf_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "qpf_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "snow_allday"=>{"in"=>0.0, "
cm"=>0.0}, "snow_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "maxwind"=>{"mph"=>10, "kph"=>16, "dir"=>"SSE", "d
egrees"=>157}, "avewind"=>{"mph"=>9, "kph"=>14, "dir"=>"SSE", "degrees"=>157}, "avehumidity"=>63, "maxhumidity"=>0, "minhumidity"=>0}, 
{"date"=>{"epoch"=>"1431298800", "pretty"=>"7:00 PM EDT on May 10, 2015", "day"=>10, "month"=>5, "year"=>2015, "yday"=>129, "hour"=>19,
 "min"=>"00", "sec"=>0, "isdst"=>"1", "monthname"=>"May", "monthname_short"=>"May", "weekday_short"=>"Sun", "weekday"=>"Sunday", "ampm"
=>"PM", "tz_short"=>"EDT", "tz_long"=>"America/New_York"}, "period"=>4, "high"=>{"fahrenheit"=>"86", "celsius"=>"30"}, "low"=>{"fahrenh
eit"=>"75", "celsius"=>"24"}, "conditions"=>"Clear", "icon"=>"clear", "icon_url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif", "skyicon"=>"
", "pop"=>10, "qpf_allday"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "qpf_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "qpf_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "mm"=>0}, "snow_allday"=>{"
in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_day"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "snow_night"=>{"in"=>0.0, "cm"=>0.0}, "maxwind"=>{"mph"=>15, "kph"=>24, "dir"
=>"ESE", "degrees"=>121}, "avewind"=>{"mph"=>12, "kph"=>19, "dir"=>"ESE", "degrees"=>121}, "avehumidity"=>66, "maxhumidity"=>0, "minhum
idity"=>0}]}}}
```

and so on. One of the fields is `"conditions"=>"Clear",`

Instead of returning the entire hash, I only want to return the current contents of the `conditions` field. When I try to do this, I get this error:
`weather.rb:18:in <main> undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

**weather.rb**

```
require "rubygems"
require 'wunderground'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def wunderground
w = wunderground::Base.new
end

w_api = Wunderground.new("2d2f765c1499b60e")

ask_location = puts "Find out what the weather is like today! Enter your zip code."
zip = gets.chomp


weather = w_api.forecast_and_conditions_for("#{zip}")

puts weather ["weather"]["conditions"]
```

I've been looking at the documentation but am not sure which part is relevant.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: this hash you provided has no conditions key, paste the full hash.

Comment: i'll add it now...I just don't know how to properly format the entire string

Comment: the hash you pasted is invalid.

Comment: Please use `pp` or `ap` to print the hash for better formatting.

Comment: @MarkThomas how do I do this? the hash is the result when I run the code with `puts weather` alone. `ruby weather.rb -pp` or `ruby weather.rb -ap` don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mark Thomas suggests, you should use something like `awesome_print` to find out the actual structure of the returned hash.

You can simply install `awesome_print` by doing:

```
gem install awesome_print
```

After doing that you can update your code to the following:

```
require 'wunderground'
require 'awesome_print'

w = Wunderground.new('2d2f765c1499b60e')

puts 'Find out what the weather is like today! Enter your zip code.'
zip = gets.chomp

weather = w.forecast_and_conditions_for(zip)
ap weather
```

Looking at the returned hash you notice that `conditions` is actually here:

```
puts weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions']
```

Comment: How do I see/copy the entire hash output from my terminal? It won't let me scroll up all the way. I'm using the Cloud 9 IDE.

Comment: I don't know the Cloud 9 IDE, sorry. Anyway, what you're looking for is at the bottom of my answer: `puts weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions']`

Comment: when I use that, it says `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: Don't put quotes around the `0`.

Comment: This does exactly what I need! Voting up and accepting now.